# Python strptime or alternative for complex date string parsing

Tags: python, parsing, python-2.7, datetime

I have been given a large list of date-time representations that need to be read into a database.  I am using Python (because it rocks).  The strings are in a terrible, terrible format where they are not precise to seconds, no timezone is stated, and the hours do not have a leading 0.  So they look more like this:

```
April 29, 2013, 7:52 p.m.
April 30, 2013, 4 p.m.
```

You'll notice that if something happens between 4:00 and 4:01 it drops the minutes, too (ugh).  Anyway, trying to parse these with time.strptime, but [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime) state that hours must be decimal numbers [01:12] (or [01:24]).  Since nothing is padded with 0's I'm wondering if there is something else I can pass to strptime to accept hours without leading 0; or if I should try splitting, then padding the strings; or use some other method of constructing the datetime object.

Also, it does not look like strptime accepts AM/PM as "A.M." or "P.M.", so I'll have to correct that as well. . .

Note, I am not able to just handle these strings in a batch. I receive them one-at-a-time from a foreign application which sometimes uses nicely formatted Unix epoch timestamps, but occasionally uses this format.  Processing them on the fly is the only option.

I am using Python 2.7 with some Python 3 features imported.

```
from __future__ import (print_function, unicode_literals)
```

Comment: Are you able to do some preprocessing? That's what this looks like it calls for

Comment: I can pre-process in the sense that I have the string in Python...  So I can do whatever manipulations I want.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The most flexible parser is part of the [`dateutil`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) package; it eats your input for breakfast:

```
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> parser.parse('April 29, 2013, 7:52 p.m.')
datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 29, 19, 52)
>>> parser.parse('April 30, 2013, 4 p.m.')
datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 30, 16, 0)
```

Comment: The only problem with using `dateutil` is that there are a handful of people out there who've been bitten by bugs in it and will loudly complain about anyone else ever using it in any circumstances. (Well, that, and it can be a bit painful to integrate with `pytz` correctly.) Otherwise, it rocks.